# How to write this equation in matrix form?

Tags: matrices

If I have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and a column vector $v$ of $n$ elements, I would like to define vector $x$ as:

$$x_{i} = \sqrt{\sum_{j}^{n}(A_{ij}v_{j})^{2}}$$

How can I write this in matrix form?

Is this ok, where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product?

$$x = \sqrt{A(v \circ v)}$$

Comment: I don't think you can write it in matrix form without using some external tools, because the equation is not linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather $\sqrt{(A\circ A)(v\circ v)}$, where $\sqrt{\bullet}$ is a “Hadamard (i.e., element-wise) square root.”

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as below:$$x\circ x=(A\circ A)(v\circ v)$$

Comment: I thought something else when I wrote first. Now I've edited my answer.

Comment: Why is the down vote?

Comment: Your previous answer was incorrect. The edited version is correct though.

Comment: yes, I wrote the previous answer mistakenly, and found the error as soon as I posted. Now I've edited it.